# MVC Application that uploads a user's file to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I have been struggling to get this right, and need advise on best practice with regards to MVC applications that read client file on users machine. My application needs to upload a excel file to the web server and then perform some validation on that file, I have struggling to get this to work,I know its a security risk to read files from users machines, but how else can I do this task, As users need to upload the file so the application can process it. I have tried to save the file to the server, but I get countless exception that either the file or part of file cannot be found, or the file user cannot access the file in both IE and Chrome, I have tested in  my local machine and everything seems to be working fine, my only issue comes where I deploy it to the server. I have tried running the application under a specific user and give that user access to the application folder where I save the file to on the web server, but still doesn't work, I have tried with ApplicationPoolIdentity but sill not coming right. What is the best way and recommended way to perform such a task in an MVC application that is hosted in IIS8 on a Windows Server 2012 R2.  Please see below the methods I tried to save the file but they dint work once deployed.

Method 1 - Here I tried using Server.Map

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var targetPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/upload");

                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName));
```

Method 2 - Here I tried saving to the applications directory where its hosted.

```
List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);


                var targetPath = @"\\servername\C$\inetpub\wwwroot\GpVisibilityUploadQA\upload\" + fileName;
                file.SaveAs(targetPath);
```

What is the best way to do this. I am really stuck. Please help.

Comment: Please post the exception message thrown at the server.

Comment: @Win Could not find file 'C:\Users\myname\Documents\Test_GP_Upload.xlsx'.  This is in IE and Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\GPUpload.xlsx'. this is in Chrome. Any idea what is happening here, I specified the loaction in my application as var targetPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/upload");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Razor syntax for a quick upload box (Assuming Home controller)

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload",
                                    "Home",
                                    FormMethod.Post,
                                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    <br><br>
}
```

And here is the controller method for obtaining the byte[] for that file

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
    byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes((int)file.InputStream.Length);
}
```

Once you have the byte[] you can just write it to temp on the server and perform any validation/manipulations you want